# Does iPad Pro App icon scale from iPad Air app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect, asset-catalog

I use Xcode 7.1. Yesterday I sent my app to iTunes connect for review. It's currently "waiting for review". Now I find out today there is an Xcode 7.2 update with app icon spot for iPad PRO. If my app gets approved the way it is, will the iPad Air icon just scale onto the iPad PRO version size for iPad Pro device or will there be a missing icon for iPad PRO version?

Comment: Every app in the app store can run on an iPad Pro and the icons for all of those apps appear. All without the fancy new 167x167 pixel icon. Your app will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app's icon will automatically scale and will appear fine on iPad Pro. However, for your next update you should add the new iPad Pro icon and screenshots.

Comment: I added the iPad PRO screenshots in iTunes Connect a while back, I did want to add an iPad PRO app icon but I didn't know how with Xcode 7.1 until later I found out, you can't. Even though I sent the app for review 2 days ago, yesterday I updated to 7.2 and made app icon for iPad PRO for the next update. Thanks to you and rmaddy for calming my nerves because i was unsure about the iPad app icon issue.